# How to keep current work directory in windows gVim when run ! command or system() function

Tags: vim, windows-10

I've used vim in linux before, it's nice to execute ":!external-command" or call "system()" function, the current work directory will pass to the triggered external command.

But now I have to work in windows(10) system, the ":!" command will execute something like "cmd.exe /c ...", while the current directory is always "C:\WINDOWS\system32\". The same thing happens with "system()" function in viml script, and as this reason, some of my plugin fail to work correctly.

For example, in gVim execute ":!dir" will just list files in "C:\WINDOWS\system32\", not the current work directory of gVim. What settings will make it behave like in linux vim execute ":!ls" to list files of current directory?

Comment: That's indeed not right and will lead to problems. On Linux, various RC files could modify the working directory, but I'm not aware of commands that are automatically executed when a Windows shell is opened. Maybe Vim itself is responsible for that; check the values of the various `'shell...'` options.

Comment: I found cmd.exe in my system will auto cd to `c:\Windows\system32` by default without the flag /d, then try `:set shellcmdflag=/d\ /c`. It still not work in gVim, but will work in noevim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not normal behavior; the Windows shell (`cmd.exe`) is supposed to maintain the current working directory, and indeed many plugins assume that this is the case when executing external commands.

As you've mentioned that the problem goes away if you supply the `/d` flag to `cmd.exe`, there must be some *autorun* command that causes the directory change:

> /D Disable execution of AutoRun commands from registry
>
> [...]
>
> If /D was NOT specified on the command line, then when CMD.EXE starts, it
>   looks for the following `REG_SZ/REG_EXPAND_SZ` registry variables, and if
>   either or both are present, they are executed first.
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
>
>     and/or
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
> ```

So, I'd suggest to check those registry keys and remove any offending command. Adding `/D` to Vim's `'shellcmdflag'` would be an alternative workaround.

Comment: my solution is delete(renmae) vimrun.exe and ```
set shellcmdflag=/d\ /c
set noshelltemp
``` because vimrun.exe will also subject this AutoRun registry.

Comment: I'm not sure whether removing `vimrun.exe` is a good solution (at least you have to remember to reapply this after upgrading Vim), and I'd rather focus on getting rid of that autorun behavior (as it might negatively other applications as well). For me, your approach really would be a last (desperate) resort.

Comment: In any case, I think the situation is clear and a solution found. Please accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark. This way, the question is marked as closed, and you increase your chances of getting answers to future questions, as this shows that you care about the answers.